# Google Cloud Load Balancing Quota 'IN_USE_ADDRESSES' exceeded. Limit: 4.0 globally

Tags: cloud, load-balancing, gcloud, quota

I set two Google Cloud load balancers for two different apps to select the closest region (US, EU) accepting HTTPS on both ipv4 and ipv6, and that works perfectly.

I need to forward HTTP requests to HTTPS. According to Google, to do that, you need to set another load balancer accepting unsecured traffic and redirecting it to the one already configured to accept HTTPS requests. (https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect)

The problem is that even I'm reusing the same IP on that second LB, an error is triggered "Quota 'IN_USE_ADDRESSES' exceeded. Limit: 4.0 globally."

Should it be considered a bug ? It seems the system is counting the number of LB bound to IP addresses instead of just each IP

Comment: As you can see in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect) that you shared, LB1 and LB2 use the same IP but with different ports. 

The error message indicates that you are surpassing your quota, so it's possible that this is not properly configured and you are using 2 IPs, which might be the cause of the quota being surpassed.

I would advise you to check this link to confirm this: [External IP addresses](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/networking/addresses/list)